# Web scraping for a RX 6800xt restock

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a web scraping program that checks the availability of the RX 6800 XT GPUs through Best Buy. This would be a very simple program if the program had to look for the status of one label, but since on Best Buy, the button to order is where the status is and this makes things more complicated. I'm struggling to figure out how to have the program check for the presence of this status. Below are the buttons and the availability of the card.

`button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block btn leading-ficon add-to-cart-button"` In Stock
`button class=btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block add-to-cart-button` Find A Store
`button class="btn btn-disabled btn-lg btn-block add-to-cart-button"` Coming Soon and Out Of Stock

I want the code to accept the 'In Stock' and 'Find A Store' as an available card. I believe I need to somehow set it to an if statement to check for the button class, but I am unsure how to do this. Below is my code for the project.

````
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from playsound import playsound

#Spoofing the user agent request
def get_page_html(url):
    headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"}
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return page.content

#Loading parser and the scraping agent
def check_item_in_stock(page_html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
    out_of_stock_div = soup.find("button", {"class": "btn btn-disabled btn-lg btn-block add-to-cart-button"})
    return out_of_stock_div.txt == "Sold Out"

#Checking the cards
def check_XFX_Reference_RX6800xt():
    url = "https://www.bestbuy.com/site/xfx-amd-radeon-rx-6800xt-16gb-gddr6-pci-express-4-0-gaming-graphics-card-black/6441226.p?skuId=6441226"
    page_html = get_page_html(url)
    if check_item_in_stock(page_html):
        print("Best Buy - XFX Reference RX 6800XT: In stock")
    else:
        print("Best Buy - XFX Reference RX 6800XT: Out of stock")

while True:
    check_XFX_Reference_RX6800xt()```
````

Comment: If soup.select_one('.add-to-cart-button') returns the correct match in each case then just check for the presence of an additional single individual unique class from each of the scenarios within the multi-valued class in matched node. For example: if node class contains "btn-disabled" then _Coming Soon and Out Of Stock_ otherwise it is available card.

Answer (score 0):

`return out_of_stock_div.txt == "Sold Out"` returns True if the button's text is "Sold Out".

So you need to reverse the outputs here:

```
if check_item_in_stock(page_html):
    print("Best Buy - XFX Reference RX 6800XT: In stock")
else:
    print("Best Buy - XFX Reference RX 6800XT: Out of stock")
```

So that they read this way:

```
if check_item_in_stock(page_html):
    print("Best Buy - XFX Reference RX 6800XT: Out of stock")
else:
    print("Best Buy - XFX Reference RX 6800XT: In stock")
```